# How to check time difference of 12 hour format in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008

I have the time 08:30 AM varchar format in sql table so I want time difference between two time in same HH:MM AM/PM format....
How can i check ???Anyone can help me????

Comment: Please add a tag for your specific database system (e.g. [tag:sql-server] or [tag:oracle], etc). Different systems have different support for date/time data types. Some have no data type that conveniently represents a time *span*, and so I'd usually recommend working with time spans outside of the database.

Comment: Oracle and/or MS SQL Server? You won't get an answer that works with both...

Answer (score 0):

Try out with the below script (for sql server).

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(8)='08:30 PM'
DECLARE @b VARCHAR(8)='12:50 AM'
DECLARE @null time='00:00:00';
```

--12 hour (I think this is logically wrong)

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),DATEADD(SECOND, - DATEDIFF(SECOND, cast(@b as time), cast(@a as time)), @null),100)
```

--for getting the difference in hours and minute

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, - DATEDIFF(SECOND, cast(@b as time), cast(@a as time)), @null) as VARCHAR(5))
```

**Output:** 
[image]